# INSERT INTO not working on newest xampp

Tags: mysql

`$query     = "INSERT INTO $stats_table_name (name, name_ID, anz_aufruf) VALUES ($plan_name, $plan_nr, $anz)";
echo "<br />".$query."<br />";
  if (!mysql_query($query) && !$error) {
    die (mysql_error());
  }`

mysql-error tells me:

```
INSERT INTO 'p_stats' ('name', 'name_ID', 'anz_aufruf') VALUES ('Laptop 1', '1', '95')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''p_stats' ('name', 'name_ID', 'anz_aufruf') VALUES ('Laptop 1', '1', '95')' at line 1
```

Where is the code wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $stats_table_name (name, name_ID, anz_aufruf) 
          VALUES ('".$plan_name."', '".$plan_nr."', '".$anz."')";
```

Answer (score 3):

the error is the wrapping of single quotes around table name.

Table names as well as column names are identifiers. They should be wrap if a name is a reserved keyword with backtick (*optional if not*). Single quotes are for string literal.

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $stats_table_name (name, name_ID, anz_aufruf) 
          VALUES ('".$plan_name."', '".$plan_nr."', '".$anz."')";
```